# Error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' al momento de convertir Str() a Int()

Tags: python, string, tkinter

Tengo un programa hecho con Tkinter, el cual de una *Entry* obtengo un numero, lo guardo en la variable llamada *nuevo_precio*,luego con un botón paso a una función la cual obtiene ese valor y lo asigna a la variable *precio* con *.get()*, luego esa variable la convierto a *int()*, pero, al momento de realizar la convención da el error del titulo.

```
def actualizar():
   precio = nuevo_precio.get()
   idv = int(idVar.get())

   df = pd.read_csv("datos.csv")
   print(df.at[idv,'Precio'])
   df.at[idv,'Precio'] = precio
   print(df.at[idv,'Precio'])
   df.to_csv("datos.csv", index=False)

   data = pd.read_csv("datos.csv",index_col="ID")
   row = data.loc[idv]

   messagebox.showinfo("Atención","Precio de {} actualizado a {}".format(row[0],precio))

nuevo_precio = StringVar()    
box = Entry(root,textvariable = nuevo_precio)
edit = Button(root,text="Actualizar",font=("Bold",13),fg="White",bg ="#4094da",command=actualizar)
```

Al momento de imprimirlo con la función *type()* es impreso como *class 'str'*
También ya intente comprobar que es digito con la funcion *.isdigit()* y siempre devuelve False.

Comment: Estás intentando el casting cuando no hay nada en el Entry...., es decir, a una cadena vacía. (`int('')`). Si el código lo tienes tal cual, `precio` se intenta calcular cuando inicias la app, cuando el Entry está vacío logicamente. ¿cuál es la idea de tu app? ¿Se deberia obtener el valor del entry al pulsar un botón? ¿automáticamente cuando se ingresa algún valor?

Comment: Vale, ¿tienes algo ingresado en el Entry cuando lanza la excepción?

Comment: Un error mio fue el no poder el código completo*, creo que ya esta lo fundamental del error, si necesitas más datos, házmelo saber.

Comment: FJSevilla: La excepción se lanza al momento de querer escribir _precio_ en un archivo .csv. Al escribir cualquier otra cosa no da error, solo si es esa variable

Comment: Perdona, he tenido que ausentarme. En tu código actual, el casting a int se lo haces al contenido de idVar (que usas cómo índice del DataFrame) no a precio.¿idVar también viene de un Entry? Si no te importa coloca la traza completa del error, no solo la linea final. Esto permite identificar sin ninguna duda si el error viene de tu casting a int o del intento de asignar el nuevo valor al DataFrame.

Comment: No te preocupes. Si idVar tambien viene de un Entry y este no presenta problemas.

Comment: Error completo:

Comment: File **[Fichero del codigo]** line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)File "edit.pyw", line 18, in actualizar
    df.iat[idv,5] = newprice.get()
**[Fichero del codigo]¨**, line 2287, in __setitem__
    self.obj._set_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
**[FIchero del codigo]**, line 2811, in _set_value
    return series._set_value(index, value, takeable=True)
**[Fichero del codigo]**, line 1223, in _set_value
    self._values[label] = value
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: nuevo_precio fue cambiado a _newprice_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se debe a que intentas asignar una cadena vacía a una celda de una columna del DataFrame de tipo `int`. Pandas al  asignar una cadena intenta hacer el casting de forma implícita a `np.int64`, pero una cadena vacía no es convertible a entero en Python:

> ```
> >>> import pandas as pd
> >>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]})
> >>> df
>
>    a
> 0  1
> 1  2
> 2  3
>
> >>> df.at[1, "a"] = "17"
>     a
> 0   1
> 1  17
> 2   3
>
> >>> df.at[1, "a"] = ""
>
> Exception has occurred: ValueError
>     invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
> ```

Debes evitar que se intente asignar un valor a la celda si `newprice` no contiene una cadena que sea posible convertir en entero, por ejemplo cuando no se ha ingresado nada en el `Entry`.

Tienes muchas formas de evitar estos problemas, entre ellas evitar que en el `Entry` se puedan ingresar caracteres que resulten en algo no convertible a entero. Un ejemplo basado en tu código reproducible:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1, 2, 3, 6],
                   "Producto": ["aaaa", "bbbb", "cccc", "dddd"],
                   "col1": [0, 0, 0, 0],
                   "col2": [0, 0, 0, 0],
                   "col3": [0, 0, 0, 0],
                   "col4": [0, 0, 0, 0],
                   "Precio": [2, 5, 6, 9]
                   })

df.set_index("ID", inplace=True)
df.to_csv("datos_test.csv")


def actualizar():
    precio = newprice.get()
    idv = idVar.get()

    if not idv: # El entry del id está vacío
        messagebox.showinfo("Atención", "No ha ingresado una id")
    elif not precio: # El entry del precio está vacío
        messagebox.showinfo("Atención", "No ha ingresado el nuevo precio")
    else:
        df = pd.read_csv("datos_test.csv", index_col="ID")
        try: 
            df.iat[int(idv), 5] = int(precio)
        except IndexError: # idv no es un ínidce válido del DataFrame
            messagebox.showinfo("Atención", "La id no es válida")
        else:
            row = df.iloc[int(idv)]
            messagebox.showinfo("Atención","Precio de {} actualizado a {}".format(row[0], precio))
            df.to_csv("datos_test.csv")

def on_validate(P):
    if all(d in "0123456789" for d in P):
        return True
    return False

root = tk.Tk()

newprice = tk.StringVar()
idVar = tk.StringVar()

vcmd = (root.register(on_validate), '%P')
price_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=newprice, validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd)
id_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=idVar, validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd)
edit = tk.Button(root, text="Actualizar", font=("Bold", 13), fg="White", bg="#4094da", command=actualizar)

tk.Label(root, text="ID: ").grid(row=0, column=0)
id_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
tk.Label(root, text="Precio: ").grid(row=1, column=0)
price_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
edit.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)
root.mainloop()
```